# Select não funciona ao clicar em botão

Tags: php, mysql, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou buscando um contrato no banco, mas ao clicar no **submit** nada é retornado:

Segue o código abaixo:

class Config{

```
// specify your own database credentials
private $host = "localhost";
private $db_name = "biodata";
private $username = "root";
private $password = "";
public $conn;

// get the database connection
public function getConnection(){

    $this->conn = null;

    try{
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
    }catch(PDOException $exception){
        echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }

    return $this->conn;
}
```

}
?>

```
<?php 
// Search from MySQL database table
$search= isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : '';
$query = $db->prepare("select from crudpdo2 where nt_pdo LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY id_pdo");
$query->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
// Display search result

if (!$query->rowCount() == 0) {

echo "Search found :<br/>";
echo "<table style=\"font-family:arial;color:#333333;\">";  
echo "<tr><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;\">Title Books</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;\">Author</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;\">Price</td></tr>";             
while ($results = $query->fetch()) {
echo "<tr><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;\">";            
echo $results['id_pdo'];
echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;\">";
echo $results['nt_pdo'];
echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;\">";
echo $results['nc_pdo'];
echo "</td></tr>";              
        }
    echo "</table>";        
    } else {
    echo 'Nothing found';
   }
?>
```

Comment: Não deu pra entender muito o código, mas já vi um pequeno erro, normalmente isso é feito em arquivos separados, um com o formulário de busca e outro com a mecânica. O erro deve ser porque voce tem o botão de submit mas não tem nenhum form para esse botão, no caso deveria ter um form com action="#"

Comment: Acho que agora está de acordo com o que voce me falou, mas mesmo assim não foi, obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 2):

Analisei profundamente o código e estava cheio de erro e práticas ruins:

- Começando no formulário, onde `name="search"` estava no `submit`
  quando se deve estar no `input` com tipo `text`.
- Outro erro foi ao colocar `'%$search%'` na sql, quando se tem de ter o `bind` e a variável do valor contendo a expressão do `LIKE`
  (%%).
- Usar `fetch()` dentro do `while` quando pode usar `fetchAll()` para pegar todos resultados de uma vez só.
- Má prática de ficar escrevendo `HTML` extenso dentro de `echo`.
- Colocar todo o estilo dentro da tag `HTML`.
  O código da página ficaria assim:

**Classe:**

conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            } catch (PDOException $exception) {
                echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
            }
            return $this->conn;
        }
    }
    ?>

**Formulário:**

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-7">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                </span>
                <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar...">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Consulta (após o formulário):**

```
<?php
// Search from MySQL database table
$cfg = new Config();
$db = $cfg->getConnection();
$search = isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : '';
$search = "%" . $search . "%";
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `crudpdo2` WHERE `nt_pdo` LIKE :search ORDER BY id_pdo ASC");
$query->bindParam(":search", $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// Display search result
if (!empty($row)) {
    ?>

    <p>Search found :</p>
    <table style="font-family:arial;color:#333333;">
        <tr>
            <td style=border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;>
                Title Books
            </td>
            <td style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;">
                Author
            </td>
            <td style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;">
                Price
            </td>
        </tr>

        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($row); $i ++) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;">
                    <?php echo $row[$i]['id_pdo']; ?>
                </td>
                <td style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;">
                    <?php echo $row[$i]['nt_pdo']; ?>
                </td>
                <td style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;">
                    <?php echo $row[$i]['nr_pdo']; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
    <?php
} else {
    echo 'Nothing found';
}
?>
```

Comment: Mas o `fetchAll()` não consome mais memoria do que `while($query->fetch())`?

Comment: Consome um pouco mais, mas o custo de fazer `fetch` para todos resultados acaba sendo o mesmo ou até maior que fazer o `fetchAll()`, pois no fundo seria a mesma coisa.

Answer (score -1):

Você esta fazendo o select errado. Para usar o Like faça desta forma:

```
$query = $db->prepare("select from crudpdo2 where nt_pdo LIKE ':search' ORDER BY id_pdo");
$query->bindValue(':search', "%".$search."%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

Voce comentou que estava com problemas no submit, mas na ultima edição da sua pergunta parece que o código do form e do botão foi retirado, já conseguiu resolver?